# How do I add damage marks to a character?

Tags: unity, textures

I am using Unity3D and I am making a melee combat game.

When a character gets damaged by a sword I need to add cut marks in enemy skin/armor. Is there a way to alter the texture to add the cut mark in the character texture ?

Can we project the damage mark onto the skin ?

Comment: 3 options I know of: 1. Use decals (best option in my opinion, but complicated in Unity, I don't know if LWRP has support of decals yet, maybe 3rd party package is required). 2. Blend between 2 textures in shader. 3. Use a particle system.

Comment: There are absolutely ways to do this, but they can get quite complicated - especially if you need to layer these effects on detailed/realistic character models that deform as they animate. It can be difficult to avoid cases where a cut does not exactly match the weapon swing that inflicted it, visibly crawls over the surface during animation, projects through a thin part of the model and renders in two places, or other similar artifacts. If you can show us the kind of character models you want to show this battle damage on, and what rendering pipeline you're using, we can suggest some options.

Comment: I am working with the placeholder assets at the moment. You can assume that the characters are low poly and very little detail is available. Think of characters like Super Hot (VR) game. This is a VR game and I would like to see the damage of the sword swings on the enemy character's body.

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ seems decals are supported in HDRP only but I found a good tutorial on achieving the same effect using shaders. I'll give it a try
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7iO9ernEmM

Comment: I also found this little addon for decals for URP 
https://github.com/Anatta336/driven-decals
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFEtdRrD2D4